# Filter an array so that only keys starting with a specified string remain

Tags: php, arrays, filter, callback

I have an array with several keys, an I'm looking for a callback to get rid of all the keys that don't meet a certain criteria (start with 'email' in this case).

I've been looking at `array_walk()` for this, but no matter what, the output is always `1`. I'm guessing that this function is not best suited for this task, so does anybody know of a better way of doing this? Thanks.

```
$test = array_walk($args, '_check_key_start_callback', 'email');

function _check_key_start_callback(&$value, $key, $str){

    return strncmp($key, $str, strlen($str));

}
```

Comment: What is this `certain criteria`?

Comment: Surely an array_filter() would be better to remove the entries you don't want than an array_walk()

Comment: Also note that $test will be a boolean 0/1 to identify whether array_walk() succeeded or not... array_walk() passes the array by reference

Comment: @MarkBaker - `array_filter()` only checks the value, not the key, and it is the key that I need to filter. Also, I think I see what you mean about `array_walk()` - i.e. it is not really for this job!

Comment: @Jelmer - My criteria is defined in code, but I will amend the question to make it clearer to all. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkBaker there is no way to use array_filter with keys

Answer (score 0):

You have to go for **array_map()** instead **array_walk()**...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, using `array_keys` and a lambda function:

```
$yourArray = array(
  'email' => 'some@email.com',
  'foo' => 'bar'
);

$allowedKey = "email";

$newArray = array_filter(array_keys($yourArray), function($key) use($yourArray, $allowedKey){

  return strncmp($yourArray[$key], $allowedKey, strlen($allowedKey)) === 1;

});
```

Anyway, lipstick on a pig.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$args = array_intersect_key(
    $args,
    array_flip(array_filter(array_keys($args), function($key) {
        return preg_match('/^email/', $key);
    }))
);
```